# Crear formulario de 1920 px con Delphi XE10

Tags: delphi

Hola tengo una aplicacion en Delphi XE10, y los formularios maximizados no se adaptan bien a como los creo.

Revisando la resolucion del monitor y de la mayoria de los monitores, se encuentra a 1920x1080 pixeles.

Pero cuando intento setear la propiedad Width del Formulario que tengo en pantalla a 1920, esta se pone automaticamente a 1555, lo mismo ocurre con el Heigth.

Entonces, de que manera puedo diseñar las pantallas en dicha resolucion o que debo hacer

Comment: No se acaba de entender muy bien lo que explicas. Lo primero, comentar que no es bueno trabajar con las resoluciones "habituales" sino con las mínimas, porque sino un cliente que no tenga una de 1900x1080 le será imposible trabajar.
Lo segundo, no comentas si estás en diseño o en ejecución.
Tercero, no sabemos el resto de propiedades del formulario; Puede haber alguna que te esté afectando.
Por último, no hay problema en cambiar el Width y el Height a 1200. Yo lo acabo de hacer en un proyecto nuevo y no hay problema. Y al ejecutarlo ese tamaño se mantiene, independientemente del monitor.

Comment: Claro. Entonces puedo desarrollar en 1280 x 720 pero luego se debe adaptar los contenidos. El problema son los componentes que hay en el formulario. Si compilo en 1280 cuando ejecuto en una maquina de 1920 sobra espacio en la pantalla

Comment: Es correcto, si sobra espacio, siempre se puede adaptar utilizando los Anchors y las Alineaciones. El problema es que si desarrollas a 1920, al que le falte espacio no hay forma de arreglarlo. 
Ninguna solución de las 2 es perfecta.
Pero digamos que en el primer caso hay solución (aunque no quede perfecta), pero es que en el segundo caso dejas al usuario si trabajar.

Answer (score 0):

He realizado algunas pruebas con Delphi 10.2.3, que es el que tengo en este momento a mano y, en mi opinión, y para responder directamente a la pregunta realizada:

**Hay una limitante en el IDE de Delphi**, para las aplicaciones VCL, que no deja establecer el valor de la propiedad `Width` y `Height` de un formulario, en tiempo de diseño, a un valor muy superior a la configuración del monitor con mayor resolución conectado al equipo en ese momento.<sup>1</sup>

Comento mis pruebas:

Inicio el IDE, creo una nueva aplicación VCL y luego una FMX, con un único formulario y le establezco propiedades a través del inspector de objetos a dicho formulario. Toda la configuración del proyecto y de Delphi es la estándar.

- Solo un monitor, 1366x768. He dejado mi Laptop de desarrollo solo con el monitor integrado, que tiene la resolución mencionada.

  - VCL, si pongo un `width` superior a 1386, es ajustado en tiempo de diseño a este valor (20 pixeles arriba de la resolución). Lo mismo ocurre con el `Height`, cualquier valor superior a 788 es convertido en ese valor.
  - FMX (2D/Blank application), sin limitaciones razonables. Si se colocan valores muy altos muestra el error: `Bitmap size too big..`, pero acepta el cambio.`
- Doble monitor, 1366x768 y 3840x2160. Una belleza 4K de mi entorno de desarrollo.

  - VCL, mismo comportamiento, diferentes límites: 3946 para `width` y 2162 para `height`. 106 y 2 pixels por encima de la resolución.
  - FMX, mismo comportamiento.

En resumen, **la solución a tu problema es tener, en el entorno de desarrollo, un monitor con una resolución, por lo menos, igual a la resolución objetivo para la que desarrollas**.

Dicho esto, uno de los retos *actuales* es realizar diseños que se ajusten a las diferentes resoluciones de los dispositivos (en este caso PC's). Esto no hay que perderlo de vista, aunque todo sistema de escritorio, sobre todo si es de uso interno, tiene *derecho* a definir una resolución mínima, máxima y óptima para la que ha sido diseñado y en las que ha sido probado.

Es más complicado con el software comercial.

---

<sup>1</sup>: En mi opinión, esto es una limitante del IDE de Delphi y podría llegar a ser considerado un BUG que, en ese caso, debiera ser reportado a Embarcadero. Desconozco si técnicamente será posible superarlo.